# How to fetch oauth2 access token using axios

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, axios

I have developed a **spring-boot** application and configured it with **oauth2**, i'm using **reactjs** at front-end and using **axios** to make rest calls, does anybody here know how to fetch access tokens using axios.

Comment: Is this question resolved? If yes, please mention the solution.